# How do I enable a bouncing effect at the end of a scroll view across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yjg8wh2/). When run on Chrome, the two vertical elements `#sidebar` and `#postbar` don't have any bounce effect at the end of the scroll view unlike what I can see on Safari (gif). How can I let a user over-scroll across all browsers for this bounce effect?

Here's css code that is relevant to the topic.

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    height:95%;
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:scroll;
    width : 190px;
    padding : 10px;
}

#postbar {
    height:95%;
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin-left:190px;
    padding : 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

[image]

edit : added code

Comment: Please post codes related to these bouncing effects.

Comment: @Sachith I added the css code of the two elements at target.